# displaying placeholder in form text field

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working with UI bootstrap and I'm using [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive. I added a `placeholder` attribute to display some text before the typing.

My controller returns a list of JSON and this is the related textbox:

```
<input type="text" 
ng-model="selected" 
placeholder="Data loaded via $http" 
typeahead="users as (users.first + ' ' + users.last + ' ' + users.gender) for users in getData($viewValue)"
class="form-control">
```

Problem: when I load the page the text box display 2 blank chars istead of the palceholder.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a plnkr? I tried a similar example but it worked just fine.

Comment: here there are an analogous plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnt3sZDJ3mCgLK8KAIOt?p=preview In that plnkr all things work fine. I don't understand why in my local example things do not work. When Chrome loads this page, in the form are printed the two `'  '` and not the `placeholder`
The only difference from plunkr above is that I'm running this html in Django and using Chrome, but I think is not important.

Comment: Probably there is a problem on the set of `<script src=''>` of my local pages (different versions of angular)

Comment: Are you sure that your service is returning data from the function getData($viewValue) ? I guess there is a problem with the service method getData. If that works fine then to start with try 'typehead = "users.first for users in getData($viewValue)" '. Just to make sure that string typecast is working just fine.

Comment: Yes service returns values (if you would like to see it in action, there is a little plnkr plnkr.co/edit/Dnt3sZDJ3mCgLK8KAIOt?p=preview )

Comment: This plnkr shows the placeholder as it should. Is there an error in this plnkr you have provided (plnkr.co/edit/Dnt3sZDJ3mCgLK8KAIOt?p=preview) ?

Comment: Nope but that plnkr show only a piece of code. My code lies in a more complex HTML context. I think the problem is in the import of JS scripts. Probably, in overall context, some other scripts (e.g. bootstrap, angular, jQuery) are loaded with other versions, creating confusion to the browser.

Comment: I doubt... would have been easier to debug if I could see the complete code.. Cant see anything conclusive as of now.. :/

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late to you, In this new plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/uIRYJ5TFFatIFYDtf1LK?p=preview I replicate the error. The difference from working plnkr lies in the scripts sources.

Comment: The problem is that the ng-model value is not blank when it is loaded. There are 2 whitespaces initially because of the typehead attribute : typeahead="address as (address.formatted_address +' '+ address.place_id +' '+ address.formatted_address) for address in getLocation($viewValue)" class="form-control">

Comment: I have updated the plnkr and it seems to be working fine and shows the placeholder while loading. http://plnkr.co/edit/wOTsgRK7gNG9HhQHT1qF?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I do not understand the reason why the old plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnt3sZDJ3mCgLK8KAIOt?p=preview works fine with the same value of typeahead attribute: `typeahead="address as (address.formatted_address + ' ' + address.place_id + ' ' + address.formatted_address) for address in getLocation($viewValue)" class="form-control"`

Comment: Yeah I was also looking into it. The problem is with the service returning data from getLocation($viewValue). In the newer plnkr we are still not getting data from the service it is only reading the concatenated string whereas in the older plnkr, we are getting proper data from the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue even with white space in the typehead attribute. The problem was with the version of angular and bootstrap you have used. I have updated the plnkr. Please find below the updated plnkr :

```
Updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mBSWeE?p=preview
```